# react-native-testing-library working async tests but getting test not wrapped in act warning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

hey all I have working tests and I know it wants me to wrap my render in an act but if I do that I get a warning stating it can't find root. yet if I then instead change it to create i can't use my getbyTestId method.

```
`it('should not render image', async () => {
        // Arrange
        // needs to be used to support async mounting methods like useeffect/componentdidmount
        jest.useFakeTimers();

        const testComment = {
            text: 'placeholder'
        } as WorkItemComment;

        await act(async () => {
            AsyncStorage.setItem('authMethod', 'msa')
        });

        const placeholderComment: WorkItemComment = testComment;
        const placeholderImage: string = 'image';

        // Act
        const { queryByTestId } = render(<CommentList workItemComments={[placeholderComment]} profilePicture={[placeholderImage]} />);

        // Assert
        await wait(() => {
            expect(queryByTestId('image')).toBeNull();
        })
    });`
```

actual component its rendering and where believe this error is stemming from.

```
`const fetch = async () => {
    const authMethod = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authMethod');
    setAuthMethod(authMethod!)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch();

  }, [props.workItemComments]);`
```

Comment: If you have specific warnings and errors, please, list them as is, don't retell their contents. Afaik `act` doesn't support promises, `await act(async () => {` is a mistake. `act` is supposed to be wrapped around component-specific code that triggers updates. AsyncStorage isn't component-specific and doesn't trigger updates.

Comment: sure,     `Warning: An update to CommentList inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output `

Comment: I stand corrected, `act` supports async..await but it's not needed for AsyncStorage because it's not a part of the component. It should be `await AsyncStorage.setItem(...)`. Are you sure about the necessity of useFakeTimers? I'd expect it to not be necessary, more the opposite, as it can potentially cause this problem. I don't see other problems for this piece of code because react-testing-library does `act` internally. Can you provide a way to reproduce the problem, maybe Codesandbox with mocked AsyncStorage?

Comment: If the problem persists and you still need a solution, you can put a bounty on it or delete the old one and re-ask it. Just keep in mind that you need to update the question with error message and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve because currently there aren't enough hints on what's wrong.